# ¿Cómo puedo setear el valor de un campo date que se envia por GET?

Tags: php, html5, mysqli, date

Buen día, deseo colocar a un campo date una fecha que venga por la variable GET, ya he intentado imprimiendo el valor en el atributo value pero no pasa nada, el resultado es como si no hubiera escrito nada. Esto es lo que he intentado

```
$fechaP=$_GET["fechaP"];
<input name="fecha_p" id="fecha_p" value="<?php echo $fechaP ?>" type="date" />
```

Esto es el resultado, no se setea el valor del campo date

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has verificado si estas recibiendo el valor? ¿Tu archivo es un .php o un .html?

Comment: Si ya verifique y el valor lo trae como año-mes-dia pero no se por que no se setea @M. Gress

Comment: Este código es vulnerable a ataques de XSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es por el formato de la fecha, tienes que cambiarlo antes de asignarlo al input, ya que debe tener todos los dígitos, por ejemplo si el día es 1 debe ser 01:

```
$fechaP=$_GET["fechaP"];
$fecha_formateada = date_format($fechaP,"Y-m-d"); //formato yyyy-mm-dd

    <input name="fecha_p" id="fecha_p" value="<?php echo $fecha_formateada;?>" type="date" />
```

Comment: Ya acabe de darle formato a la variable y se presenta un nuevo error, creo que el formato date no se puede setear                                                           **Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoWeyder\editarMensualidad.php on line 82** @Carmen

Comment: Pasa tu variable fecha primero a tiempo con strtotime y luego la formateas, así debería funcionar

Answer (score 1):

El formato que pasas al `date` el `<input>` debería ser `2017-07-01` ([rfc3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)), ósea tienes que convertir la fecha a este formato `Y-m-d`

```html
Si funciona (value="2017-07-01")
<input name="fecha_p" id="fecha_p" value="2017-07-01" type="date" />
<br>
No funciona (value="01-07-2017")
<input name="fecha_p" id="fecha_p" value="01-07-2017" type="date" />
```

Comment: ya la converti pero no se deja setear se presenta este error              **Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoWeyder\editarMensualidad.php on line 82**

Comment: @JuanDavid - Comprueba el valor del `$_GET`.. te he puesto unos ejemplos

Answer (score 0):

Esta fue la solucion, me toco darle el formato a la fecha

```
$originalDate = "2010-03-21";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```